# *102 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream

Tags: nginx, php, centos

Установлен NGINX + PHP-FPM

В директории сайта создан каталог PhpMyAdmin. При переходе в директорию, показывает ошибку

> 502 Bad Gateway

В логах Nginx

```
2013/12/02 12:43:04 [error] 20822#0: *102 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 195.131.87.194, server: paxgame.ru, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock:", host: "site.ru"
```

В логах php-fpm

```
[02-Дек-2013 12:48:10] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 21400[02-Дек-2013 12:48:10] NOTICE: ready to handle connections[02-Дек-2013 12:48:13] WARNING: [pool www] child 21401 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 3.499667 seconds from start[02-Дек-2013 12:48:13] NOTICE: [pool www] child 21407 started
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vim /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf/path/to/unix/socket = /tmp/php-fpm.sock
```

Ну вы поняли...

Comment: Не до конца я понял. Во первых у меня нет каталога /etc/php5

Comment: У вас во первых в вопросе вопроса то нету. Во вторых посмотрите где у вас конфиги от пакета php-fpm. В третьих пропишите в конфига fpm пула конектор на unix-socket.

Comment: А вопрос такой: почему появляется 502 ошибка NGINX при обращении к папке с PhpMyAdmin. Сокет прописан:; Note: This value is mandatory.;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000listen = /tmp/php-fpm.sock

Comment: А какой нибудь phpinfo отработает?

Comment: Да. А вот в PMA не зайти...502 error..

Comment: А запрос долго висит или сразу 502 выплевывает?